# empty field validation in jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

I have 3 text fields.

The first field is the only mandatory field, but if the second field is not empty the first and third text field should not be empty.

How to do this validation in jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
var set = $('input[type="text"]');
if(set.eq(0).val().length == 0 || (set.eq(1).val().length > 0 && set.eq(2).val().length == 0)) {
   //throw error
}
```

Comment: should probably have `$.trim` in there too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a simple logical algorithm

```
if ($('#field2').val() != '' && ( $('#field3').val() == '' || $('#field3').val() == '')) {
    return false;
}
```

Otherwise, You can find some plugins to validate form there : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: FWIW, comparing strings is more expensive than checking the length of them.